# How to mock useJsApiLoader from @react-google-maps/api

Tags: react-google-maps-api

How can I mock useJsApiLoader? I'm trying the following:

```
jest.mock("@react-google-maps/api", () => ({
  useJsApiLoader: () => ({
    isLoaded: true,
    loadError: undefined,
  }),
}));
```